# Remote docker containers

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I have Machine A ( windows 10 ) and Machine B (Linux centOS),I have docker installed and working in both of them . 
What I want to do is ,remotely run the `Docker run` command to spawn containers on the Linux machine B ,using my windows power shell [or any other tool ] on machine A .
I can have the Dockerfile required to be placed on Machine B ,but I would prefer to have it in Machine A .
Is this at all possible ,I was looking at the documentation for Docker-machine but I am not able to find the exact piece of information I need.

Comment: Not sure if this is possible with windows. In linux I think you could provide access to the `/var/run/docker.sock` of one machine to the other.

Comment: Okay considering both machines are on linux,if I do provide access ,post that do I need to run commands in Machine A  like `DOCKER_HOST =Machine B IP:2376 sudo docker images`